# Draw a cube using GridPlot in JMathTools

Tags: java, 3d, plot, jmathplot

I want to draw a cube using jMathPlot. The cube's points are:

(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,2),(1,0,2),(1,1,2),(0,1,2)

I have these variables:

```
double[] x = {0,1,0,1};
double[] y = {0,1,0,1};
double[][] z1 = {{1,1,2,2},
                 {2,2,1,1},
                 {1,1,2,2},
                 {1,1,2,2}};

Plot3DPanel plot = new Plot3DPanel("SOUTH");
plot.addGridPlot("cube", Color.red ,x, y, z1);
```

It doesn't work and honestly I still don't understand why `z` must be a 2D array?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the source code for JMathPlot, I think Z is 2D array because Z's are given as the result of some function f(x,y). See [GridPlotsExample](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=zDWJ049DWMl0yyzmNEtVx4wpA5s&cid=aWIomnrowDs&s=addGridPlot&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=false#L3) on how to construct double[][] for z argument.

Comment: I saw it before I post this question and I know that Z is 2D array but the question is how to set its values to draw a cube ?